# How to add an listener to when onBindViewHolder is called after calling recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged()?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement where I want to set the state of an object after calling `notifyItemChanged` so that that change is reflected when view is **updated next time**. However, if I do this -

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(itemPosition)
itemList[itemPosition].someValue = true
```

then `onBindViewHolder` gets called with someValue = true since `onBindViewHolder` is called after some time after calling notifyItemChanged. 
So, is there some way of knowing when onBindViewHolder has been called after calling notifyItemChanged after which I can set the desired value?

I tried `locationsRecyclerView.adapter?.registerAdapterDataObserver(RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver)` but unfortunately, `onItemRangeChanged` is called much before `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly you want to change the value of an object the next time after the item in the recycle view already changed then you can add a counter to the item and when counter is uqual 2 do something like that

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindViewHolder(position)
        holder.counter++

        if(holder.someValue==true&&counter==2){
            //do something

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Solves my problem. However, not marking this answer as correct since it does not answer the main question of if there's a way to add a listener to the onBindView call after notifyItemChanged..

Comment: why? do you want to connect the code to the main activity? there is way but it's not something built in